# Discord.py (Bot sending response twice / running commands twice)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
@bot.command()
@commands.has_permissions(manage_messages=True)
async def purge(ctx, amount: int):
    await ctx.channel.purge(limit=amount)
    await ctx.send(f'Successfully purged {amount} messages.')
```

^^ That is just one of the commands. Every time I use it, it pastes "Successfully purged {amount} messages" twice. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Is it possible you're running 2 instances of the bot? Maybe you ran it, lost the window somewhere and ran it again?

Comment: Open the process manager (`Ctrl + Shift + Esc` on windows) and search for hidden python processes, if you're running through an IDE you can also close it, if that doens't work you can try restarting your PC

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot executing the same command twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383931/bot-executing-the-same-command-twice)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably running to instances of your bot, I notice you are a new contributor so instances mean 2 versions of your bot.

So check if your running 2 files and stop them if you can.

If this doesn't work and you would like an easy way out of this, there is a way you can stop all instances.

First go to the [Discord Developer Portal](https://discord.com/developers/applications), from there you click the bot you are working on.

[image: Choose the bot your working on.]

For example, if your working on Among Memer click Among Memer.

Now on the left side of your screen you should see this drop down bar.
[image: Dropdown bar]

Click Bot.

[image: Bot]

Now, click re-generate token. This will change the token so that the token in your code or in other code isn't valid anymore.
Copy that token.

Then your going to need to go into your code,and paste the token in the place where your old token was.