# Why is my "ctx.send()" statement printing out twice?

Tags: python, docker, discord

Whenever I ran the "def Register" function I get "getting you registered message twice" and when I write to the file, it writes to it twice as well. I'm not sure what's going on.
Here is my code:

```
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import member
from discord import Intents
import datetime

current_time = str(datetime.datetime.now())
user_instance = None


intents = discord.Intents.all()
intents.message_content = True

bot = commands.Bot(intents=intents, command_prefix="!", case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command(name="register", description="Register a User")
async def register(ctx):
    global user_instance
    try:
        await ctx.send("Getting you registered...")
        user = ctx.author
        user_instance = User(user)
        with open("user.txt", "a") as file:
            file.write(str(user) + "\n")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        await ctx.send("Oops! There was a problem Registering you. Speak with your admin.")


@bot.command(name="play", description="Playing the Guessing Game")
async def play(ctx, number):
    global user_instance
    print(user_instance)
    try:
        if user_instance is not None:
            await user_instance.play(ctx, number)
        else:
            await ctx.send("Please register first using !register.")
    except discord.HTTPException as e:
        print(f"Oops! There was a problem starting the game. Speak with your admin. Command Error: {e}")


@bot.command(name="points", description="Amount of points user has")
async def points(ctx):
    global user_instance
    await user_instance.point(ctx)
```

I ran it in a docker container but ended up with the same result.

Comment: I'm guessing that `register()` is being called twice.

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66645271/discord-py-bot-sending-response-twice-running-commands-twice