# Discord Bot is randomly messaging multiple times on command when its not supposed to

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

the discord bot that i created is supposed be activated when someone says hi however when this happens multiples outputs are sent. I'm knew to discord.py so this might be a stupid question that has an easy fix however, not really sure how to do this:

```
import discord


bot = discord.Client()


@bot.event
async def on_ready():

    guild_count = 0


    for guild in bot.guilds:

        print(f"- {guild.id} (name: {guild.name})")


        guild_count = guild_count + 1


    print("SampleDiscordBot is in " + str(guild_count) + " guilds.")


@bot.event
async def on_message(message):

    if message.content == "hello":

        await message.channel.send("hey")

    if message.content == "what is your wisdom o' truth bot":
        await message.channel.send("Stupid, this is!")


bot.run('KEY')
```

Comment: Are you sure you are not running different code with the same key elsewhere?

Comment: Make you properly stop the bot each time before running again. If you `Ctrl`+`C` in the terminal, and try the command on Discord, if the bot still responds then you accidentally have multiple instances of the bot running. Restarting your computer will fix this. An alternative is going into the developer portal on Discord and changing your bot token

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Bot executing the same command twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57383931/bot-executing-the-same-command-twice)